# Changing the "day" contents in pgfgantt charts titles

Tags: pgfgantt

When generating a title with the days in a Gantt chart (package `pgfgantt`), the day number is generated by

```
\gantttitlecalendar{day}
```

and it will generate the day number in the form `01`, `02`, ... etc.

Is it possible to manipulate this format? For example, adding the initial of the weekday to it, like `M01`, `T02`, `W03`, ...? (this may seems strange but it is quite commonly used in school calendars in Spain).

Comment: MWE in the answer... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible way to add a `wday` specifier:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\makeatletter
\def\pgfcalendarweekdayletter#1{%
\ifcase#1M\or T\or W\or T\or F\or S\or S\fi%
}
\ganttset{%
calendar/wday/.code={%
    \ifgtt@calendar@eol\ganttnewline\fi%
    \begingroup%
    \pgfcalendar{}{\gtt@calendar@startdate}{\gtt@calendar@enddate}{%
        \gantttitle{%
            \pgfcalendarweekdayletter{\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday}%
            \pgfcalendarcurrentday}{1}%
    }%
    \endgroup%
    \gtt@calendar@eoltrue%
    }%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{ganttchart}[
        title/.append style={fill=black!10},
        x unit=10pt,
        time slot format=isodate,
        hgrid, vgrid,
        ]{2017-9-4}{2017-9-17}

        \gantttitlecalendar{year, month=name} \\
        \gantttitle{W1}{7}
        \gantttitle{W2}{7}
        \\
        \gantttitlecalendar[
            title label font=\ttfamily\tiny,
            title label node/.append style={rotate=90},
        ]{wday} \\

    \ganttbar[inline]{task}{2017-9-8}{2017-9-14}

    \end{ganttchart}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Which will produce:

[image: output]